# htaccess 301 redirect - Remove query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect the urls which have query strings to the top page like this

from

https://cococo.com?abc=123

to

https://cococo.com

because when i type https://cococo.com?abc=123 it also display the top page so I think it's not  seo-friendly.

how to whrite the .htaccess to solve this problem?

the follow one is wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^\?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}?$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule to remove query string only on landing page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [L,R=301]
```